# selected added div be draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-draggable

I want my added div be draggable.
I can do it by adding `$("div[id^=new-text]:last").draggable();`
But this is not work.

My complete example [link](http://finance.usermd.net/customizer/index.html)

This is the code:

```
var count=0;
$(function() {
    $(".add-new").click(function() {
        $('.image').append("<div id='new-text_"+count+"' contenteditable>Edit me</div>");
        count++;
    });

    $('#writable').keydown(function() {
        var writable_value = $('#writable').val();
        $("div[id^=new-text]:last").text(writable_value);
    });

    /*change font family*/
    $("#fs").change(function() {
        //alert($(this).val());
        $("div[id^=new-text]:last").css("font-family", $(this).val());
    });

    $("#fc").change(function() {
        //alert($(this).val());
        $("div[id^=new-text]:last").css("color", $(this).val());
    });

    /* change font size */
    $("#size").change(function() {
        $("div[id^=new-text]:last").css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
    });

    $("div[id^=new-text]:last").draggable();
})
```

Comment: i've edited your question with that comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want any of the added text to be draggable. You will be looking for the following:

```
$("div[id^=new-text]").draggable();
```

Instead of this what you have currently:

```
$("div[id^=new-text]:last").draggable();
```

You was only picking the last new-text element, so you need to select all the elements with the `id` containing new-text.

Answer (score 0):

If I add draggable it is work but is problem with editing of selected div.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madmaxxx/a7qyd0na/1/)

```
        $(".add-new").click(function() {
        $('.image').append("<div id='new-text_"+count+"' contenteditable>Edit me</div>");
        count++;
    });
```