# Change attribute selected in contenteditable

Tags: jquery

How can I change the CSS attribute? In my case `font-size` but not last but selected

```
$("#size").change(function() {
    $("div[id^=new-text]:last").css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madmaxxx/a7qyd0na/13/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The title seems unrelated to the question

Comment: I thought this was stackoverflow.com, not english.stackexchange.com. Give the guy a break...

Comment: I think the issue is "contenteditable" in the title which is a valid attribute in HTML but doesn't seem to be remotely applicable to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of the selected element. Put a `click` handler to set a global var to the `$(this)` - where `$(this)` is the clicked element.

```
var selectedText = null;
$('.image').on('click','.new-text', function(){
    selectedText = $(this);
});

$("#size").change(function() {
        selectedText.css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/a7qyd0na/14/

Comment: thank can you look on my other problem with draggable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147401/selected-added-div-be-draggable?noredirect=1#comment54109017_33147401